# How can i run cypress cucumber test cases using tags in parallel

Tags: tags, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Can anyone help me on how to run cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@feature-tag' in parallel on gitlab pipeline.. I tried using

"e2e:test": "cypress-tags run -e -- TAGS='@feature-tag'",
"test:e2e": "run-p --race "e2e:test -- {@}" --"
but it didn't work although it is working when i use it with cypress run instead of cypress-tag run,

"e2e:test": "cypress run",
"test:e2e": "run-p --race "e2e:test -- {@}" --"
Here this work but i can not use tags with cypress run. It will be really grateful if you can help me with any solution.

Comment: Does it work in your local?

Comment: @Raju I am able to run the test cases using tags but it's not running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no native support from `cypress-cucumber-preprocesseor` to achieve this. But there are other options in the market if you want to consider them. They are discussed in [this](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/299) issue.